# Can't remote access on docker mariadb

Tags: docker, networking, mariadb, remote-access, forwarding

i'm facing a huge problem after updating my docker version from 17.10.0-ee-preview-3 to 20.10.20.

After putting back my mariadb docker, i cannot access it from outside anymore, even with the maridb conf file to accept remote connection and the docker run with publish attribute.

I used `docker network create -d nat network` to attach my container network but nat is not available anymore on that version, which can be the issue, i hope.

First, i used this docker run to create it : `docker run --name GreenDB --env MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --publish 3306:3306 mariadb`

Even with the mariadb conf file updated to accept remote, i still can't access it, here's the file.

The MariaDB configuration file :

```
# #
The MariaDB/MySQL tools read configuration files in the following order:
0. "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" symlinks to this file, reason why all the rest is read.
1. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf" (this file) to set global defaults,
2. "/etc/mysql/conf.d/*.cnf" to set global options.
3. "/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/*.cnf" to set MariaDB-only options.
4. "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# #
If the same option is defined multiple times, the last one will apply.
# #
One can use all long options that the program supports.
Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# # --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
# #
If you are new to MariaDB, check out https://mariadb.com/kb/en/basic-mariadb-articles/

# #
This group is read both by the client and the server
use it for options that affect everything
# #
[client-server]
Port or socket location where to connect
port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
[mariadbd]
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve
max_connections=250
bind-address=0.0.0.0

!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Did i forgot something ?

Here's the docker inspect just in case :

```
[
    {
        "Id": "3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6",
        "Created": "2022-10-25T13:01:18.815337Z",
        "Path": "docker-entrypoint.sh",
        "Args": [
            "mariadbd"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 35535,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2022-10-26T09:19:23.2219827Z",
            "FinishedAt": "2022-10-26T09:19:22.7991342Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:14f1097913ecb422c61f9b35604339c1ac74394e7df7f84f765917b018605b5f",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6/3516b606eb5ccc87db03c877821409462d3444c204e94e305a859d3a887199a6-json.log",
        "Name": "/GreenDB",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "",
                        "HostPort": "3306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "shareable",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                50,
                120
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e13bc3176c62a8f3fd27986eba038d51fa40f6455748f8914c92fed0b5255f54-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d42e6f685222a9ccdb24758762fe863f9cd56faf67dedfa05b57a05222a1bc5c/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2e35877fcf192254d1dcfc28a26ed7135d486cf8ae1eb156da7e494047aff060/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/0619e74b00d5de6ecc1a2317a3af6eb35328c86d1f8cf12af8a4cf49142eac1b/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/39c485f1146b25739b2ba393918683752f5c91d6fcfc257d927c82ed9f0fb061/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fa35ceb2ecaca4f90301e72455bdaa6bdaec1446abb088529c772306f48d96d6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c31a6859826ce1917105cb64649843ea57592b042db6355eb50fc40a6a158ccd/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b7eea3560be9644ac53182bf90c943690f1185c5c091ff0f518b051061c5c84d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/7aeddc2e48e28ce55188fd4f3fbf386b700556b8760c3d01d7aae08bfb48f2ac/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/bce33e0ae06075f8034070144a9575c07f7c65ae08151811d5c37f19493d5ed4/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b25cfc2b4f08ebe012050a95b76df3e4841743c7090b46bfe6e53e2b04047543/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/5763da58e94725b158adbd0f68159ebb882b05d3a605f10e7ce8a7d64f7c3548/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e13bc3176c62a8f3fd27986eba038d51fa40f6455748f8914c92fed0b5255f54/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e13bc3176c62a8f3fd27986eba038d51fa40f6455748f8914c92fed0b5255f54/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e13bc3176c62a8f3fd27986eba038d51fa40f6455748f8914c92fed0b5255f54/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "volume",
                "Name": "ed58f390a1c3c98e522bdeb335aec420d0f37d2f1b606024ba9b43f63b49d846",
                "Source": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/ed58f390a1c3c98e522bdeb335aec420d0f37d2f1b606024ba9b43f63b49d846/_data",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/mysql",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "3516b606eb5c",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "MARIADB_PASSWORD=*",
                "MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=*",
                "MARIADB_USER=*",
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.14",
                "MARIADB_VERSION=1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mariadbd"
            ],
            "Image": "mariadb",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "11ace205ac5b407ba6da2496ae0d911edf1fbf70796d50764b5215002cb269bc",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "3306/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "3306"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/11ace205ac5b",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "pepiniere": {
                    "IPAMConfig": {},
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": [
                        "3516b606eb5c"
                    ],
                    "NetworkID": "0f1522a4430c7ab37a28171177cd6eacc24b57d4641a1b27a4528ea10a7e1bf5",
                    "EndpointID": "a563790191df8896a55af6f394810f98898849da00cacaf42fff0d49a2082eb1",
                    "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.19.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:13:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

I can't figure out what has changed from the last container.

Do you have an idea ? I'm stuck and desperate.

I'm pretty that's not about my database users ?

```
MariaDB [Project_Green]> select host,User from mysql.user;
+-----------+-----------------+
| Host      | User            |
+-----------+-----------------+
| %         | Intelligence    |
| %         | express         |
| %         | interpreteddata |
| %         | rawdata         |
| %         | root            |
| %         | weatherservice  |
| localhost | express         |
| localhost | interpreteddata |
| localhost | mariadb.sys     |
| localhost | rawdata         |
| localhost | root            |
| localhost | weatherservice  |
+-----------+-----------------+
```

edit : Added the docker logs as @10195153 said

```
PS C:\Users\admin\Documents\e> docker logs GreenDB
2022-10-26 12:17:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204 started.
2022-10-26 12:17:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2022-10-26 12:17:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MariaDB Server 1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204 started.
2022-10-26 12:17:48+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Initializing database files


PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MariaDB root USER !
To do so, start the server, then issue the following command:

'/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation'

which will also give you the option of removing the test
databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
strongly recommended for production servers.

See the MariaDB Knowledgebase at https://mariadb.com/kb

Please report any problems at https://mariadb.org/jira

The latest information about MariaDB is available at https://mariadb.org/.

Consider joining MariaDB's strong and vibrant community:
https://mariadb.org/get-involved/

2022-10-26 12:17:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2022-10-26 12:17:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2022-10-26 12:17:50+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204) starting as process 101 ...
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 46590; transaction id 14
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@de84fbaa6ec2' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@de84fbaa6ec2' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2022-10-26 12:17:50 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
2022-10-26 12:17:51+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2022-10-26 12:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Securing system users (equivalent to running mysql_secure_installation)

2022-10-26 12:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Stopping temporary server
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] mariadbd (initiated by: unknown): Normal shutdown
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 221026 12:17:52
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "./ibtmp1"
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 46590; transaction id 15
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] mariadbd: Shutdown complete

2022-10-26 12:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server stopped

2022-10-26 12:17:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: MariaDB init process done. Ready for start up.

2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] mariadbd (server 10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204) starting as process 1 ...
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using transactional memory
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of transaction pools: 1
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using crc32 + pclmulqdq instructions
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] mariadbd: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using liburing
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128.000MiB, chunk size = 2.000MiB
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File system buffers for log disabled (block size=4096 bytes)
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12.000MiB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12.000MiB.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: log sequence number 46590; transaction id 14
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Warning] You need to use --log-bin to make --expire-logs-days or --binlog-expire-logs-seconds work.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 221026 12:17:52
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2022-10-26 12:17:52 0 [Note] mariadbd: ready for connections.
Version: '10.9.3-MariaDB-1:10.9.3+maria~ubu2204'  socket: '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the exact error from the remote access attempt? What do `docker logs GreenDB` show? (edit question with this information).

Comment: Note the default mariadb container image (and server generally) does allow remote connections.

Comment: When i try to access it from my express.js backend, i get timeout

Comment: Can you access it via the Docker host's terminal (*not* from within the container using `docker exec`) using the `mysql` command?